# One dice game between 2 players probability

Tags: probability, dice

I need some help with my dice game probability calculations,here's the rules:

Two players A and B compete by throwing successively a classic 6-sided dice.It's A who starts.The player who wins is the one whose cumulative points after his throw exceeds n at least the cumulative points of his opponent$(|scoreA-scoreB|\ge n)$.A clearly has an advantage since when he makes his accounts he has one more throw than B.So what are the probabilities of A winning or B winning?